# Why another <Alert> function can not be reached when <Alert> has been called once using Metrial UI and React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am calling handleRead()inside handleReply(), but currently, the alert message when calling handleReply() is “Mark as read “. I wonder is there a way that I can overwrite handleOpenAlert("Mark as read", "success") while calling handleReply() so that alert message will be “Reply successfully” without deleting handleOpenAlert("Mark as read", "success") inside handleRead()?

Material UI Alert Component:

```
   <Alert severity={openAlert.severity}>{openAlert.message}</Alert>
```

Setting Alert:

```
   const [openAlert, setOpenAlert] = React.useState({isOpen: false, message: "", severity: ""}) 
   const handleOpenAlert = (mess, sev) => setOpenAlert({isOpen: true, message: mess, severity: sev}) 
   const handleRead = async () => { 
         await markMessageRead(selectedMessage.id) 
              .then(res => { 
               handleOpenAlert("Mark as read", "success") 
              }) 
              .catch(err => { 
                console.log(err.response) 
              }) 
   } 
   const handleReply = async () => { 
         await replyToMessage(selectedMessage.id, messageRef.current.value) 
             .then(res => { 
              if (res.status === 200) { 
                 handleRead() 
                 handleOpenAlert("Reply successfully", "success") 
              } 
             }) 
             .catch(err => { 
              console.log(err.response) 
             }) 
   }  

return ( … 
         <Button onClick={handleRead}>Read</Button> 
         <Button onClick={handleReply}> Reply</Button> 
);
```